# External imports in Babel 7 do not get transpiled

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I'm currently migrating a codebase from Babel 6 to 7. The code is made up of multiple individual projects with their own configs.

The `main` project imports files from `external` however the scripts being imported from `external` by `main` aren't being transpiled and fails on "Unexpected token import". Scripts located directly in `main` *do* transpile correctly.

I'm using the following command within the `main` project to transpile the scripts:

```
babel-node ./index.js
```

Another project uses Webpack to do the same thing and handles everything correctly.

This setup also worked fine with Babel 6.

---

`.babelrc` for `main`

```
{
"ignore": [
    "node_modules"
],
"presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": {
            "node": "current"
        },
        "useBuiltIns": "entry"
    }]
],
"plugins": [
    [
        "module-resolver", {
            "alias": {
                "External": "../external"
            }
        }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
]}
```

---

`.babelrc` for `external`

```
{
"presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react"
],
"plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
]}
```

---

I've created an example to detail my problem at:

https://gitlab.com/nerdyman/babel-7-external-import-broken

---

TL;DR I'm trying to import scripts from outside of a project's root directory but they don't get transpiled by Babel, the scripts from within the project *do* transpile.

Comment: What's your Webpack config for `babel-loader`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks for the reply. This isn't for Webpack, it's just using `babel-node ./index.js` as seen in https://gitlab.com/nerdyman/babel-7-external-import-broken/blob/master/main/package.json#L8

Comment: Oh gotcha, I was reading too fast :P

Comment: @nerdyman did you solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @TonyT unfortunately not - though I haven't looked at it in a month or so. I posted on the Babel Slack but they were stumped. I ended up sticking with Babel 6 for now.

Comment: Where you ever able to solve this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to fix this by following [this](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8309#issuecomment-439406408) comment.

The solution is:

1. Move `.babelrc` in the main project to `babel.config.js` and make it a CommonJS module
2. Add `--ignore=node_modules` when running `babel-node` from the main project

This still seems pretty hacky and Babel doesn't seem to acknowledge the `ignore` property within `babel.config.js` it **must** be specified as a flag.

Babel 7 appears to only allow imports within the directory the babel config is in, however explicitly setting the `--ignore` flag overrides this.

You can view my [working demo](https://gitlab.com/nerdyman/babel-7-external-import-broken/tree/master/babel7/main) and the [diff](https://gitlab.com/nerdyman/babel-7-external-import-broken/commit/1b7d43469174040a93a0f963872960a47926817f) of what I changed to get it working.

The [issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8309) is still open on GitHub so there may be a better solution in the future.

Comment: With NextJS - there is no need for any other preset than the 'next/babel' the magic source i was missing was the --ignore=node_modules - thank you.

Comment: This works for great for `babel-node` (+1)! But regular `babel` build in `main` doesn't include the `external` dependency. How did you solve that?

Answer (score 0):

current directory's `.babelrc` won't be loaded while import files in external directory, you may place a `.babelrc` in that directory and set its `presets` by relative path(instead of short name):

> {     "presets": ["..\pad\node_modules\babel-preset-env"],
>     "retainLines": true }

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this would work? I'm not sure that this solves my problem, the goal is make each project autonomous, importing using aliases only.

Comment: @nerdyman if the file in the external directory contains es6 code, it should be translated when it's imported, but if there's no .babelrc in that directory, the translation will fail. since that directory is just a common code holder and not a `project`(no package.json, no node_modules), even we put the same .babelrc (which is used in the root)  there , the babel plugins won't be loaded. so put there a special .babelrc with plugins referenced by path, the babel loader will find them in root and make the translation correctly.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem here, external is its own project and has its own package.json and .babelrc as seen [here](https://gitlab.com/nerdyman/babel-7-external-import-broken/tree/master/babel7/external).

Comment: yeah, I could run your example in babel6, but not work in babel7.